# Phonegap android build fails while using 'cordova-plugin-video-editor' plugin

Tags: android, cordova, video, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I was developing an app which requires a functionality to trim video by duration. I came across [Cordova Plugin Video Editor](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor) plugin and its documentation said it has everything I needed (get video info and trim video). But the problem is that Phonegap build fails to build android. From log, I got this error

```
BUILD FAILED
/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:597: Invalid file: /project/cordova-plugin-video-editor/videoDemo-android-ffmpeg-java/build.xml
```

Anybody got an idea what might have caused this error. Do anyone know any other plugin that can trim video by duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused because I was using phonegap version 3.7.0. When I upgraded to cli-5.2.0, the issue was fixed. App was successfully built after this.